# Rails Dynamic Controller Authentication (Devise + Cookie or Token + Headers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, cookies, devise

SO...

I currently have 2 rails controllers: one for devise authentication and another for token authentication. I am trying to create a new controller that can be used to use devise authentication when a cookie is present or token authentication using headers when the cookie is not present.

My instinct is to have my new controller have 2 variables, one of each type of authentication controller and use a `before_action` or `before_filter` that will check for the cookie and forward the request to the correct controller.

Note that my devise authentication controller has a `before_action :authenticate_user!` and my token authentication controller has a `before_action :authenticate_using_headers`, but I only would like 1 called depending on the manner of which my API is hit.

Any insight on how I can achieve this elegantly with minimal changes to my existing controllers is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `authenticate_using_headers` returns `nil` or `false` if the authentication fails, you can do this in your `application_controller`

```
def authenticate_token_or_user!
  authenticate_using_headers || authenticate_user!
end
```

Then in controllers where you want to enable both:

```
before_filter :authenticate_token_or_user!
```